# Why WScript.StdOut.Write method behaves differently in VBS vs. JScript?

Tags: vbscript, jscript, wsh, windows-scripting

I have two small programs in VBS and JScript:

**VBScript.vbs:**

```
For i=0 To 255
   WScript.StdOut.Write Chr(i)
Next
```

**JScript.js:**

```
for ( var i=0; i <= 255; ++i )
   WScript.StdOut.Write(String.fromCharCode(i));
```

When I execute they in the command-prompt, they show different results:

```
C:>cscript /nologo VBScript.vbs
 ☺☻♥♦♣
♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]
^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~⌂??'ƒ".┼╬^%S<O?Z??''""--~Ts>o?zY ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®
¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþ
ÿ

C:>cscript /nologo JScript.js
 ☺☻♥♦♣
♫☼►◄↕‼¶§▬↨↑↓→←∟↔▲▼ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]
^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~⌂???????????????????????????????? ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­
®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüý
þÿ
```

Previous output may be explained because some operative difference in JScript's fromCharCode method vs. VBScript's Chr function. However, if a try to redirect the output to a disk file, the result is very different:

```
C:>cscript /nologo VBScript.vbs > VBScript.txt

C:>cscript /nologo JScript.js > JScript.txt
C:\JScript.js(2, 4) Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid procedure call or argument

C:>dir *.txt

15/01/2013  05:48 p.m.               128 JScript.txt
15/01/2013  05:48 p.m.               256 VBScript.txt
```

In this case, both programs use *the same* WSH method under *the same* conditions, so I don't understand why VBS correctly generate the file with 256 characters, but JScript issue an error and just generate the first 128 characters.

What happens here? Is there a way to correctly generate the same file with 256 different characters in JScript? TIA

Antonio

Comment: Interesting, then redirect to file both vbs/js print 128 bytes and fail here with the same error. +1 for this question.

Answer (score 6):

first,

the logic of your codes are not the same.

the counting on your **VBScript.vbs** starts at `ZERO(0)` while your **JScript.js** starts at `ONE(1)`.

change the increment operator in your JScript to make them the same:

```
for ( var i=0; i <= 255; i++ )
    WScript.StdOut.Write(String.fromCharCode(i));
```

second,

the functions you used are not the same
because they both return different result
on a per character context.

the `Chr()` function returns ASCII characters,

while the `fromCharCode()` function returns Unicode characters that may have 1 to 4 bytes per character.

therefore, the `Å` character from the ASCII set is different from the `Å` character from the Unicode set.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding what @OpenTechnologist said, how about you using `ChrW()` instead of `Chr()` in the VBScript as that will come closer to the essence of fromCharCode(), i.e. outputting Unicode.

Comment: I see your point. However, I am interested in the _opposite_ question, that is: how to _directly_ generate Ascii characters in JScript? I solved this problem already adjusting the generated codes with a factor that is variable for each character beyond 127...

Answer (score 0):

I am going to be as a necromancer for a moment rising this too old discussion. But a few days ago I have encountered almost the same issue.

I had needs to write to STDOUT an arbitrary text containing Unicode and redirect it to a file. Googling helped me, and the solution was always under my hands:

My findings:

```
object.CreateTextFile(..., unicode)
object.OpenAsTextStream(..., format)
object.OpenTextFile(..., format)
```

where

- `object` is FileSystemObject, Folder or File
- `unicode` is boolean with `true` meaning to create a Unicode file
- `format` is tristate with `-1` meaning to open the file as Unicode

All these methods returns a TextStream object writing in **UTF-16 (Little endian) with BOM** if configured to handle files in Unicode mode.

By default `WScript.StdOut` and `WScript.StdErr` write always in ASCII mode. To switch them to Unicode mode we have to run WSH in Unicode mode explicitly:

```
cscript //u SCRIPTFILE
```

It's global switch and cannot be turn off or on during runtime. Output is becoming changed to **UTF-16 (Little endian) without BOM**.

It shouldn't be a big issue when everything is coming from the only source or in the only mode. But it can't be applicable if outputs are collected from different sources in different modes (ASCII and/or Unicode).